How to improve my life with teachings from hinduism?
I'm very depressed about my life. My health is bad, my relationships aren't great, I have not enough wealth.
How to work or motivate myself from the teachings of hinduism and to better my life in every aspect of health, wealth, jobs and family?

Suggest hearing Kathas of Premanandji Maharaj on YouTube for motivation.

Try chanting batuk bhairava nama mantra, or Kala bhairava nama mantra , shiva Sahasranama or the hanuman chalisa.

First: Hey Parth, this is just a phase. Stay resilient, because better days are coming—they always do.
Second: Remember, God helps only those who help themselves.
Third: I admire your drive to improve your situation. You’ve already taken the first steps: recognizing the need for change and beginning the journey. You are indeed helping yourself, God will indeed help you.
Finally and most importantly: Many answers lie in our scriptures, like the Bhagavad Gita, and in the lives of our deities. For example:
When Lord Ram faced hardships, he didn’t sit questioning, "Why me? Why was I sent to exile? Why was Sita taken? Why was Lakshman injured?"
Instead, he acted. He faced his challenges head-on, showing us the value of action over dwelling on hardship. Our deities exemplified resilience, wisdom, and Dharma (righteousness)—qualities that can guide us through any difficulty.
Explore the Gita, the Ramayana, and the Mahabharata. They’re not just stories; they’re our history and legacy, filled with lessons from our ancestors who can be some of the greatest teachers.
I was once in your situation,
Simply Going through these stories, simply reading Geeta has helped alot. I take the better decisions now, I collect good karma now, and I follow my dharma, my dharm. I am a much better human.
My situation didn't improve immediately, but the collective effort of my many small good decisions inspired by the deities way of living, or the way they have prescribed for us; it improved slowly, but steadily.
Boond boond se Banta hai Sagar.
Every single good decision taken with inspiration from them is a drop of water, and your simple task is to fill a Glass of water. Keep doing the deeds. The drops will fill the glass.
